# Calculating average difference between date() entries in an array (in ms)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on learning React; and started with the metronome from here: https://daveceddia.com/react-practice-projects/

I'm extending it by building a tap tempo system.

So, I'm not really sure what's going on, but it definitely is NOT getting an average here in milliseconds (taps go nuts when I start the stopTapTempo function). I've never used date() like this before, so any guidance is appreciated! I've already caught a few things here (realized I forgot to reverse the for loop for the subtraction aspect), but not really sure what else is needed.

```
handleTapTempo = () => {
    var { taps } = this.state;

    if (taps.length === 0) {
        taps[0] = [new Date()];
        console.log("Starting taps: " + taps);
    } else {
        taps.push(new Date());
        console.log(taps);
    }
}


stopTapTempo = () => {
    var { taps, i } = this.state;

    for (i=taps.length; i < 0; i--) {
        if (i>0) {
            taps[i] = taps[i] - taps[i+1];
        } else {
            taps.pop();
        }
    };
    console.log("Avg Taps: " + taps);
    this.timer = setInterval(
        this.playClick,
        (taps) => taps.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / taps.length
    );
    this.setState(
        {
            count: 0,
            playing: true
        },
        this.playClick
    );
}
```

Basically, after the for loop in stopTapTempo, it should output an array like 565, 345, 775 (depending on how many taps you use - if you tapped 4 times, then you get 3 numbers in the result here). Then I average those numbers and start up the metronome with the new tempo.

Comment: Could you post a codesanbox to it? There might be mistake with taps[i+1] in the first iteration

Comment: I wouldn't add dates with a single + operation. I would suggest using a library like moment.js or day.js to perform date operations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved; Took a step away, and caught a number of issues. I ended up doing this to get the ms for the array (just not as used to working with Date() in this sort of situation):

```
var x = new Date(); var y = x.getTime();
```

That solved my issue with the array, and then I fixed all the other weird bugs. Just gotta clear my taps array with each start and we'll be all set. I'll try to remember to share the results :)